# twitter user screen name after oauth in android

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

i want to know my screen name after logged in to twitter using oauth in android.

I used OAuth authentication,
my code for it

```
new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider) {
    this.context = context;
    this.consumer = consumer;
    this.provider = provider;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
{
try {
    Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
    final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
        Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

and after it, i worked on onNewIntent(Intent intent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

```
private OAuthProvider provider;
private OAuthConsumer consumer;
final Uri uri = params[0];
final String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(consumer.getToken(),consumer.getTokenSecret());
provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);
HttpParameters params1 = provider.getResponseParameters();
String userName = params1.getFirst("screen_name");
Log.v("user name >>>>>>>>", userName);
```

Comment: Man, You are the only one who gave correct anwser to the question - how to get screen_name from oauth twitter api. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Rojer and Manikanand Can anybody provide whole procedure to open twitter and get screeName. I am stuck here. Please provide tutorial if any.